# Python for loop start counter initialization

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
for iteration in range(len(list) - 1):
  index = iteration +1 #This is the line which has no effect on the inner loop
  for index in range(len(list)):
    if list[iteration] > list[index]:
      newmin  = list[index]
      newminindex = index        
  if iteration != newminindex :
    swapnumbers(list,iteration, newminindex)
```

The above is a code snippet I wrote for selection sort algorithm. However I see the inner loop start counter always starting from 0. Request for expert comment.

Comment: When you say `range(15)` (for example), it really says `range(0,15)`. Using only one argument simplifies it for you (the programmer), but it is really saying the latter. You should simplify it to `for index in range(iteration + 1, len(myList)):`. Also, try not to reuse variable names like you did here. When you say `for index in...` you reset the value of index you gave it the line before. As I assume you thought, setting index before does not affect its starting vale in the `for` loop. The value of index gets changed to the default value of `range(oneArg)`:0, and with 2 args, the first value.

Answer (score 9):

The `for index in range(len(list))` loop executes the loop body with `index` first set to `0`, then `1`, then `2`, etc. up to `len(list) - 1`. The previous value of `index` is ignored and overwritten. If you want `index` to start at `iteration + 1`, use the 2-argument form of `range`:

```
for index in range(iteration + 1, len(list)):
```

Answer (score 3):

You really should be using [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) for stuff like this, as you can loop through the index and the value at the same time (which will save you the hassle of using two for-loops).

```
for i, j in enumerate(list):
    print i, j
```

Your inner loop is overriding the variable `index` that you defined in the first loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
for index in range(iteration + 1, len(l)):  # don't use "list" as a name
```

`index` is being reassigned anyway within the `for`-loop so `index = iteration + 1` is not having any effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
for index in range(iteration + 1, len(list))
```

Comment: Also, what arshajii said about the reserved keyword, "list"

Comment: `list` is not a keyword. It's a builtin identifier; reassigning it is valid, but generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'd upvote TerryA's answer. However I like to improve his answer to meet OP request and make it conform to Python3

His example with a starting counter 1 would be:

```
for i, j in enumerate(list,1):
  print (i, j)
```

and for easier understanding I would replace i and j with something like below. It probably explains it better: (both will work, but it's not obvious what i and j represent)

```
for list_number, list_value in enumarate(list,1):
  print ("number ", list_number, " is  ", list_value)
```